# VHDL Clock problem while creating modulo 16 counter

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I've created this simple mod16 counter using basys3 board and something is not right with my clock. The code itself do works, however one count (changing from "1" to "2" etc.) last 40 seconds, instead of 1 second! I've tried to lower the "clk_vector" if condition to 1 but it didn't help either.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity mod_16_k is
    Port ( switch : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           CLK1 : in STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           led : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
end mod_16_k;
architecture Behavioral of mod_16_k is

signal      clk_vector   :integer;
signal      clk_vec2      :std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 

begin
zegar_wew : process(CLK1)
begin

if(CLK1'event and CLK1 = '1')  then
    clk_vector <= clk_vector + 1;
        if(clk_vector = 100000000) then
            clk_vec2 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(clk_vec2)  + 1);
        end if;
end if;
end process;
led <= clk_vec2;
end Behavioral;
```

The .XDC lines for clock are:
[image]

If we check the basys3 datasheet, the clock is connected to "W5" port.
[image]

Do you have any idea, what might be the problem in here? It might be connected with detecting the rising edge of an clk, however all of the changes (from 1 to 2 etc.) last ~40 seconds.

Comment: Check this part " begin
zegar_wew : process(CLK1)
begin". Which pin is your internal clock?

Comment: W5 just like in the second photo

Comment: Check this example, you need to assign PINs IN and OUT, https://www.fpga4student.com/2017/08/vhdl-code-for-clock-divider-on-fpga.html, your variable "zegar_wew" is assigned but doing nothing.

Comment: i mean.. "zegar_wew" is a name of a process that main argument is CLK1 which is variable in std_logic type. Im checking for rising edge of process argument and if its true - then im working on signals created in architecture. I dont really understand what do you mean by "assigned but doing noithing"

Comment: 2^^32 = 4294967296 values, divided by 100,000,000 clocks per second gives you one event every 42.9 seconds when recognizing a single value. Use a counter with a period of 1 second.

Comment: Jonathan advice is really helpful - the program continues even after 100.000.000 counts up to exactly 4294967296. The solution was to restart after certain value :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you forget to reset `clk_vector` once it reaches 1 second. Because it is an integer, it is 32 bits, thus will count 2^32 instead of 100000000.

This should work:

```
If(CLK1'event and CLK1 = '1')  then
        if(clk_vector = 100000000-1) then
            clk_vector <= 0;
            clk_vec2 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(clk_vec2)  + 1);
        else
                clk_vector <= clk_vector + 1;
        end if;
end if;
```

Also, notice that to count 1 second, you need to count up to `100000000-1`, we start counting from zero!

Comment: am i wrong in here? vivado is suppose to cut all the data exceeded provided range.

Comment: Yes, but nothing in your code says *not* to use the 32 bits, you are some making a comparaison on a specific value.  You should constrain your integer with `signal clk_vector : integer range 0 to 100000000-1;`. Even then, it won’t count up to 100000000-1, but to the next power of two since the other bits will be discarded by Vivado.